# How to copy selected property from one object to another in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a library management system in pure javaScript for learning purpose. I want to copy id and name of the book into student object.

```
var book = {
    id: "b1",
    name: "JavaScript",
    price: "$10",
    author: "Jack"
}

var student = {
    id: "S1",
    name: "Rob",
    bookList:[]
}
```

I want to do this:

```
var student ={
    id: "S1",
    name: "Rob",
    bookList:[{id:"S1", name:"JavaScript"}]
}
```

Guys, if there is some other way to implement library management please tell that also...

Comment: Why not just place `book` reference to `student.bookList`?

Comment: student.bookList.push(book)?

Comment: `student.bookList.push(book)` - see [Array#push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: `student.bookList.push({
        id: book.id,
        name: book.name
      });`

Comment: Thanks@JakeWeary..I am new to javaScript..can you please explain how can I keep multiple books assigned to one student..Thanks.

Comment: Please read the documentation and go through some basic tutorials on your own. You are missing fundamental knowledge and Stack Overflow is not a tutorial writing service. All these things have been explained in many places in great detail, you will have to commit some time into learning the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just push to the array

```
student.bookList.push({ id: book.id, name: book.name });
```

**DEMO**

```js
var book = {
    id: "b1",
    name: "JavaScript",
    price: "$10",
    author: "Jack"
}

var student = {
    id: "S1",
    name: "Rob",
    bookList:[]
}

student.bookList.push({ id: book.id, name: book.name });

console.log(student);
```

If you need to have multiple books inside a student, just keep pushing the objects under **`bookList`**.

**DEMO**

```js
   var book = {
        id: "b1",
        name: "JavaScript",
        price: "$10",
        author: "Jack"
    }
   var book2 = {
        id: "b2",
        name: "AngularJs",
        price: "$15",
        author: "Tod"
    }
    var student = {
        id: "S1",
        name: "Rob",
        bookList:[]
    }
  
    student.bookList.push({ id: book.id, name: book.name });
    
    student.bookList.push({ id: book2.id, name: book2.name });
    

    console.log(student);
```

Comment: Thank you! @Sajeetharan..I tried to upvote your anwser but shows less than 15 reputation.. I am new to these things.. thank you